# HTML pass constant or function to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing

I'm currently writing a JavaScript library to plot functions in the browser. The user includes the library and adds a `div` of specific class to the page. He is able to tell the library what to plot via `data-*` attributes of the `div`.

Now I do want that the user is able to pass constant values or javascript-functions as arguments and my library reads the constant or evaluates the function. How would I do this?

**Example:**

```
<script>
function range-value() {
  var range = document.getElementById("random-range");
  return range.value;
}
</script>

<div class="plot-example" data-plot-xMin="-1"></div>
<div class="plot-example" data-plot-xMin="range-value"></div>
```

This would make the lib way more flexible, but how would I handle the incoming data intern?

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: What should the fiddle contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval and type of to tel the differrent between a function and a num and call the function. You can just use eval if "rangeValue" (eval => a function) is written "rangeValue()" (eval => number).

```js
function rangeValue() {
  var range = document.getElementById("random-range");
  return range.value;
}

function rangeValue2(num) {
  return num + 10;
}

var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("plot-example");

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var val = eval(divs[i].getAttribute("data-plot-xMin"));
  var trueval = null;
  if (typeof val === 'function') {
    trueval = val();
  } else {
    trueval = val;
  }
  document.write("<br>" + trueval);

}
```

```html
<div class="plot-example" data-plot-xMin="-1"></div>
<div class="plot-example" data-plot-xMin="rangeValue"></div>
<div class="plot-example" data-plot-xMin="rangeValue2(3)"></div>
<input id="random-range" value="2" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you really much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by get the attribute's value and access to the function by `window['the_function_name']`.

Like this:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.plot-example'), function(elm) {
  var f = window[elm.getAttribute('data-plot-xMin')];
  if (f) {
    elm.innerHTML = window[elm.getAttribute('data-plot-xMin')].call();
  }
});
```

```html
<script>
function rangeValue() {
  var range = document.getElementById("random-range");
  return range.value;
}
</script>

<div class="plot-example" data-plot-xMin="-1"></div>
<div class="plot-example" data-plot-xMin="rangeValue"></div>
<input type="range" id="random-range" />
```

Comment: I think jQuery shouldn't be used here

Comment: Now this will not work with `-1` as attribute. It'll try to call a constant. You can take a look at the answer above you.